# Buscar rápida por uma string ou parte dela em um Array

Tags: ruby

Possuo o seguinte `array`:

```
images = %W(
  droido 7midias vigilantes sebrae_mei dpe_saed websat ferpamweb dpe_chronus dpe_plantao
  promocast lolitaface dpe_intranet cha_bar clinica_sorriso droido_mascote bom_sabor
)
```

O que eu quero é uma maneira **Ruby-Like** de buscar uma `string` como *"cha_bar"* ou apenas parte da `string` como *"cha"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheguei a um resultado bem simples usando *expressão regular* e `index`

```
images.index{|s| s =~ /cha_bar/}
```

ou

```
images.index{|s| s =~ /cha/}
```

Isso irá retornar a posição da `String` buscada.

Comment: pode usar tbm `images[x].include? 'cha'`

Comment: Bom também! gostei da expressão regular por ser menor, mas fica a dica.

Comment: Humm, mas include pode ser mais interessante quando trabalho com variáveis...

Comment: sim, mas no final pode-se dizer que as estruturas são as mesmas, a diferença é que quando se usa `{|s| s ...}`, o ruby já cria um `foreach` para seus valores

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar o método [`Enumerable#detect`](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.2/enumerable#method-i-detect) (ou [`Enumerable#find`](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.2/enumerable#method-i-find)) e ele irá retorna o primeiro elemento que retornar `true` na condição do bloco:

```
images.find {|s| s =~ /lan/ } # => 'vigilantes'
```

Ou, caso você precise de todos os elementos que tornem a condição verdadeira, você pode usar [`Enumerable#select`](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.2/enumerable#method-i-select) (ou [`Enumerable#find_all`](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.2/enumerable#method-i-find_all)):

```
images.select {|i| i =~ /lan/ } # => ["vigilantes", "dpe_plantao"]
```